# Stop .animate() once the last item reached w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with overflow set to hidden. Two triggers allow to scroll items inside the layer with overflow.

I have an overflow div with items hidden. I can scroll the boxes inside the hidden area on click of UP/DOWN elements:

```
$("#up").click(function(){
    $("#container").find(".box").animate({"top": "+=20px"}, "slow");
});
$("#down").click(function(){
    $("#container").find(".box").animate({"top": "-=20px"}, "slow");
});

<style>
#itemsList {
    height:60px;
}
.box {
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
</style>

<div id="container">                        
    <div id="up" class="scroll">UP</div>
    <div id="itemsList">
        <div id="item1" class="box">item 1</div>
        <div id="item2" class="box">qweqweqwe</div>
        <div id="item3" class="box">qqqqqqqq</div>
        <div id="item4" class="box">eeeeeee</div>
        <div id="item5" class="box">rrrrrrrr</div>
        <div id="item6" class="box">tttttt 11</div>
    </div>
    <div id="down" class="scroll">DOWN</div>
</div>
```

I need to disable .animate() once the scroll reaches first or last elements. The code above works, but it does not stop .animate(). I've added some code to check for position of the scrollable elements (see jsfiddle link) but it seems like I messed something up.

Here's my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VP5Xb/8/).

Comment: You should look into the 'ScrollTo' jquery plugin.. This will allow you to scroll to a specific item (with animation) rather than arbitrarily adding 20px to the scroll position. You could also accomplish this easily by obtaining the y coordinate of the items and changing the scrolltop value.

Comment: True, but I rather skip plugins in this case. Perhaps I can scroll to the item without using dimensions...

Comment: agreed. The same concept applies. Find the next item to scroll to.. use `obj.position().top` to find its y coordinate and set the `$('#container').scrollTop(y);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the 'ScrollTo' jquery plugin.. This will allow you to scroll to a specific item (with animation) rather than arbitrarily adding 20px to the scroll position.

Here is a [quasi-working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VP5Xb/12/). Note that I updated the jQuery to 1.7 and included the [scrollTo library](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js) http://jsfiddle.net/VP5Xb/12/

You could also accomplish this easily by obtaining the y coordinate of the items and changing the scrolltop value.

Comment: Wow, cool. What does console.log(currentTopItem) do? Is it needed? Also, will it work with v.1.4.4? It is a part of the project that uses this library and I cannot update it...

Comment: console.log is a debug line and can be removed.

Comment: Is there a wy to detect when it reaches bottom or top? and trigger an event, like classToggle?

Comment: of course. The `else` clause of the `if (tempBox.length>0) {` statement will be triggered when a next or previous item cannot be found (essentially, you are are the top or bottom).

Comment: That's great, but how do I know which one? I'd like to add some sort of visual indicator that it is disabled, i.e. can not be scrolled any longer. And I want to trigger something like addClass() once the first/last is reached, and not on click after they reach it. This is a great plugin, I just need to get a few things figured out. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: you know based on `$(this).attr('id')`. If it is `up` you are at the first item.